# Why can we use Cursors directly?

Tags: android, cursor

Looking at the source code for android.database.Cursor, I notice that all its member functions are undefined.

If so, how can we directly use Cursor? Shouldn't we have to use some concrete class that implements Cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't we have to use some concrete class that implements Cursor?

You *do* "use some concrete class that implements `Cursor`". For example, when you query SQLite, you get a [`SQLiteCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) back. We just tend to reference it as the interface type (`Cursor`), in case we change the implementation sometime (e.g., switch to querying a `ContentProvider`).

If you look at [the JavaDocs for `Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), you will see a list of classes that implement this interface.

Comment: I was really confused because I went to check what `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()` returns and it was also a Cursor and not SQLiteCursor. Actually, my noobish eyes haven't been able to see SQLiteCursor in action anywhere. Hence the question.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent: "it was also a Cursor and not SQLiteCursor" -- the *method signature* of `rawQuery()` says that the return value must be of type `Cursor`. The implementation of `rawQuery()` will, by default, return a `SQLiteCursor` (though there are ways of providing factory objects to have it use something else).